# Simplify array from many values to fewer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, simplify

I have an array with many numbers (165) and want to 'simplify' the array to fewer numbers (50). The reduced array should still be representative for the 165 original numbers.

For example:
If I had this array with 8 values `[2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 4, 9, 3]` and would ask to reduce it to 4 values, I want to receive this array `[3, 5.5, 2.5, 6]`

Currently I have a function that works when the reduced number and the original number can be divided (as with 8 and 4) but when I try using it with let's say 165 values that should be simplified to 50 values it returns me 54 values:

```
const array = [28, 71, 64, 116, 128, 8, 78, 172, 142, 96, 12 ... 165 values]
const valuesToSum = Math.floor(array.length / 50); // 50 is the wanted array length 
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i % valuesToSum !== 0 || i === 0) {
        sum += array[i];
    } else {
        returnArray.push(sum / valuesToSum);
        sum = 0;
    }  
}
return returnArray;
```

In the end this should be a JavaScript function but if someone could explain me this on a mathematical level it would help me a lot.

Comment: do you have 165 or 100 numbers? please add the numbers and the wanted result.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)...

Comment: I don't see how you're getting 54 values in the result. You should be getting 3 values.

Comment: Your code also ignores the values that are left over after the first 150 elements.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, sorry i corrected it. And I know that I'm ignoring the left over after the first 150 numbers that is my problem

Comment: Use `math.ceil()` instead of `math.floor()`.

Comment: @Barmar that does not help since the function now returns 41 values

Comment: In your example you are "simplifying" the original array by essentially grouping array elements into same size chunks and returning the mean of each chunk. Now that you want to transform the array from an arbitrary number of elements to a smaller but still arbitrary number of elements, how do you want to handle the fact that you will not be able to break the array into same size chunks? In other words, `165 / 50 == 3.3` so do you want to average 49 chunks of 3 and 1 chunk of 18, 35 chunks of 3 and 15 chunks of 4, etc?

Comment: Will you always have 165 numbers or is array length dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the exact number of groups you want, you can't round off the number of elements to group. For instance if you want to reduce from 165 to 50, some of the groups will have 3 elements, some will have 4.

To do this, use nested loops. The outer loop increments by the size of the group, while the inner loop increments by 1 within the group. The rounding happens when you convert this inner index to the array index.

```js
const array = [28, 71, 64, 116, 128, 8, 78, 172, 142, 96, 12]

function reduceArray(array, newSize) {
  const returnArray = [];
  const valuesToSum = array.length / newSize;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += valuesToSum) {
    let sum = 0;
    let j;
    let start_i = Math.floor(i);
    for (j = start_i; j < Math.min(start_i + valuesToSum, array.length); j++) {
      sum += array[j];
    }
    returnArray.push(sum/(j - start_i));
  }
  return returnArray;
}

console.log(reduceArray(array, 4));

const bigArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 165; i++) {
  bigArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
let result = reduceArray(bigArray, 50);
console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: that looks good for a small number of values, but with my 165 values I still get only 42 values back. Even if I ask for 50.

Comment: I know, I've been revising it.